# "WY" representation of QR factorization -- implementations?

Tags: matrix-factorization

I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ where $m \gg n$ and I want to compute the full QR decomposition $A = QR$. Where $Q$ is an orthogonal $m \times m$ matrix.

[Bishof & Van Loan (1987)](https://ecommons.cornell.edu/bitstream/handle/1813/6521/85-681.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) describe that $Q$ can be represented as the sum of a low-rank matrix plus the identity matrix:

$$Q = I + W Y$$

Where $W \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$. I implemented this myself in Python, and it works! But it is still pretty slow because it involves a for loop over the $n$ columns. I'm curious if anyone has pointers for libraries that already implement this... If not I might try re-implementing in Julia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A later paper, Schrieber and Van Loan 1989, describe a "compact" WY representation which is more storage efficient,
$$
Q = I - Y T Y^T
$$
where $T$ is upper triangular. The paper by Elmroth and Gustavson 2000 then use this compact WY representation to derive a recursive QR algorithm, which is quite elegant and efficient as it is based on Level-3 BLAS operations.

A C implementation of the Elmroth and Gustavson 2000 algorithm is in the GSL library: [here](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gsl.git/tree/linalg/rqr.c).

LAPACK provides a fortran implemenation of Elmroth and Gustavson in the [DGEQRT3](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dd/d9a/group__double_g_ecomputational_ga3ad112f2b0890b3815e696628906f30c.html#ga3ad112f2b0890b3815e696628906f30c) routine. The standard LAPACK QR routine ([DGEQRF](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/dgeqrf.f.html)) also uses the WY approach, as does the rank revealing QR algorithm (technical note [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn114.pdf)). However these (non-recursive) algorithms are quite a bit more complex, and not so elegant.

**Schreiber, Robert, and Charles Van Loan. "A storage-efficient WY representation for products of Householder transformations." SIAM Journal on Scientific and Statistical Computing 10.1 (1989): 53-57.**

**Elmroth, E. and Gustavson, F.G., 2000. Applying recursion to serial and parallel QR factorization leads to better performance. IBM Journal of Research and Development, 44(4), pp.605-624.**

Answer (score 2):

Just building on @vibe's answer. Here's a quick sketch of how to access and work with LAPACK to do this with Python/scipy. This uses the Elmroth & Gustavson algorithm under the hood.

```py
from scipy.linalg.lapack import dgeqrt

def tall_qr(A):
    m, n = A.shape
    assert m > n
    V, T, INFO = dgeqrt(n, A)

    # Extract R from V.
    R = np.zeros_like(V)
    R[np.triu_indices_from(R)] = V[np.triu_indices_from(V)]

    # Extract elementary reflectors in V.
    V[np.arange(n), np.arange(n)] = 1.0
    V[np.triu_indices_from(V, 1)] = 0.0

    # To recover the dense orthogonal matrix use:
    #   Q = np.eye(m) - V @ T @ V.T
    #
    # However, the dense matrix multiply (Q @ B) should be
    # slower than B - (V @ T) @ (V.T @ B) for large matrices.

    return (V, T), R
```

Comment: If you need to form the full $Q$ (which is rare and probably unnecessary), there is a more efficient way to do it (see the gsl_linalg_QR_unpack_r routine in the GSL link above). You correctly note that computing $Q B$ or $Q^T B$ is more efficiently done by applying the matrices $V,T,V^T$ individually to $B$. See the QTmat routine in the GSL link. Finally, note that the DGEQRF routine handles the case $N < M$ while E&G does not. It may be possible to extend E&G to this case, but I have not tried (and I'm not aware of others doing it either).

Comment: Also, if your matrix happens to be so tall that you cannot fit the entire matrix in memory at one time, you can use the TSQR algorithm (https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.2159), which can use E&G for the individual QR updates of a block of rows.

Comment: @vibe -- I'm trying to figure out if there's a blas / lapack routine that will do the low rank update `B - (V @ T) @ (V.T @ B)` inplace on B? Right now I'm just writing it out in numpy, but `B` has quite a large number of columns, so the sub-expression `(V @ T) @ (V.T @ B)` instantiates a large matrix in memory. DLARFB seems to be the right method to use? Unfortunately, it doesn't seem exposed in `scipy.linalg.lapack`...

Comment: You might try DGEMQRT, which looks like a wrapper function for DLARFB. There is also a DGEMQR function which looks like a wrapper for DGEMQRT. Also, is there a reason you don't want to use the standard DGEQRF function for your $QR$ decomposition?